# Google Optimize Audience Targeting on dataLayer variable - (actual value not found)

Tags: shopify, google-datalayer, google-optimize, data-layers

I have in my code a dataLayer.push for this variable

```html
<script>
 window.dataLayer.push({
  'enterTest': 'enter'
});
</script>
```

and when I run the console.log on dataLayer it shows but in Google Optimize I have these settings:
[image]

[image]

But when I debug in live mode, it says :
Enter Test 2 equals enter (actual value not found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had the same problem and found out that Google Optimize loads faster than Data Layer. To check this use [Google Tag Assistant](https://tagassistant.google.com/) to check where in the firing schedule did Google Optimize load.